# I'm trying to set the value of a column based on it's data type, but I'm getting an error 'Can't convert varchar to numeric'

Tags: sql, case

This is a bit more simplified version. I'm looping through a list of columns that exist in one new table but not the older version of the same table so I can add those missing columns. I then check what the data type is supposed to be for those missing columns and update the table with a default value. In the below code the column name has a varchar data type, but it gets the error that it can't convert to numeric because it's an option in the case statement. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```sql
UPDATE enr   
      SET [someColumnName] = CASE 
         WHEN (SELECT DATA_TYPE
                FROM dataRestore.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'Stuff'
                  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'someColumnName') = 'varchar' THEN ''
        WHEN (SELECT 
            DATA_TYPE
            FROM dataRestore.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME  = 'Stuff'
              AND COLUMN_NAME = 'someColumnName') = 'bit' THEN 0
        END
FROM dbo.Stuff enr
```

The error goes away if I put quotes around the numeric values in the case statement, but then it's trying to enter varchars into the bit data type columns which will give an error.

Comment: Set to NULL instead, no matter what data type it is.